# Storing user responses to questionnaires using controllers in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember to create a profiler app (like one of those personality quizzes you sometimes get in magazines). It presents a series of 10 questions, each with 7 multiple choice answers, with each answer having a different allocated score. Each response gets added up to a score out of 100. Users will eventually be able to store their answers, so they can redo it at a later date to see if they've improved.

But being (very) new to Ember, I have got stuck on collecting and storing a users responses as individual records.

My problem is that I use a QuestionsController to load in the question from a Fixture (Question), together with its possible Answer (a separate, related Fixture).

So when someone clicks on an answer (e.g. using a button, but when I've got my head round it I'll probably use radio buttons), it's capturing their response... but what do I do with it next?

I thought the best approach would be to have a separate ResponseController that created records of the individual responses (which I could then total), but Ember expects the captured responses to be handled by the QuestionsController, not the ResponseController (which is what I think *SHOULD* be doing it).

I can't seem to get my head around how to do this, particularly how all the different parts of Ember fit together and interact across controllers.

**The Javascript**

```
// Models

App.Question = DS.Model.extend ({
label: DS.attr('string'),
    answers: DS.hasMany('App.Answer')
    });

App.Answer = DS.Model.extend ({
    question: DS.belongsTo('App.Question'),
    label: DS.attr('string'),
    value: DS.attr('number')
});

App.Response = DS.Model.extend ( {
    question:   DS.attr('string'),          // Question_id that was responded to
    score:      DS.attr('number'),          // The score of the selected answer
    answer:     DS.belongsTo('App.Answer')  // The answer 
    });

// Controllers

App.QuestionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend( {

    select: function( question, score, answer ) {      

    // this next bit is clearly not right, but I don't know why...
        App.Response.storeResponse( question, score, answer );


    }
});

App.ResponseController = Ember.ObjectController.extend( { 

    storeResponse: function( question, score, answer ) {

    // this next bit is clearly not right, but I don't know why.
        createRecord ( { question: question, score: score, answer: answer  } ); 
    }
});
```

**The HTML**

```
<!-- The Template for the Questionnaire -->

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id='questions'>
<H2>Questions</H2>
{{#each question in controller}}
    <div><span>{{question.id}}</span> {{question.label}}</div>
    <div>{{partial "answer"}}</div>
{{/each}}
</script>

<!-- The Template for the Answers -->

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id='_answer'>
<ul>
{{#each answer in question.answers}}
    <li><button {{ action "select" question.id answer.value answer.id }}{{answer.label}}</li></button></li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

**Progress**

I have the templates working fine; it displays the questions and answers correctly (or at least as I'd expect). The button is capturing the correct response. But I really don't know how to get the data from there into storage.

The responses I get in the console vary (depending on my attempts to solve) from "Undefined" to "Can't find variable storeResponse".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `needs` api to communicate across controllers. For instance you can declare that the `QuestionController` `needs` access to the `ResponseController` with,

```
needs: ['response'],
responseBinding: 'controllers.response',
```

Ember will then inject the response controller instance into the `QuestionController` which can be accessed with `this.get('response')`. Then your `select` action handler can invoke `storeResponse` on it.

```
select: function( question, score, answer ) {      
  var controller = this.get('response');
  controller.storeResponse(question, score, answer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a clear answer and example. I will come back and let you know the outcome.

Comment: It works! I had been getting lost as many of the examples I had found were either deprecated or only provided snippets that didn't explain how to apply it properly. Thank you again.